# Magento 2.2.3 - CMS Home Page not showing for other store view

Tags: magento2, admin, magento2.2, cms

I have a primary store view `home` that's attached to the default store and configured (in Stores > Configuration > General > Web > Default Pages) with a specific CMS Home Page (also called `home`).  That works fine.

I have another store view, `store2`, that's attached to a second store and configured with a different CMS Home Page (`store2`), and that one doesn't work.  Instead, it shows the same CMS Home Page as the primary `home` store view.

This happens even though I've set the `home` CMS page to only be available for the `home` store view, and the `store2` CMS page to only be available to the `store2` store view.  I've also tried changing the keys for the CMS pages in case they were conflicting with the store view keys somehow.  No dice.

I should note that `store2` has a custom theme which was copied from `home`'s theme (I've tried having that custom theme inherit from both `home`'s theme and from its theme's parent; neither seems to help matters.)

I should also note that `store2` exists as a directory on the server just below root.  It contains symlinks to app, lib, pub, and var, a copy of the root's `.htaccess` file, and a modified `index.php` file, per our server provider's instructions.

Lastly I should note that we used MGS Page Builder to create the initial homepage, and that extension's export/import feature to produce the CMS homepage for `store2`.

I've also run `setup:upgrade`, `cache:flush`, and `indexer:reindex` (we're in dev mode so no deployment).  No luck.

Any idea what I'm missing here?

Comment: Did you assign the homepage from store > configuration > web default page for all stores?

Comment: Yes, changed the scope to each store view and assigned there.